# Online Whiteboard using Socket Programming in Java

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, javafx, whiteboard

I am trying to create an online whiteboard where the server draws/sketches something on a panel and the client/clients can see it live.

I am using JavaFX scene builder for the application.

I know how to serialize objects into streams, but are JavaFX objects(like scenes, layouts, panels) serializable?

I can't actually find any way to update the scene in client dynamically following the server. Please Help!

Comment: JavaFX UI components (ie. `Node` subclasses) are not serializable. You don't want to pass the UI components anyway, you want to define a "model" that represents the state of the application, and transmit the model. This question is really too broad: it's hard to envision an answer to this that wouldn't either be an entire application or a complete tutorial.

Comment: Yes, **never** serialize the *View*, and instead always strive to serialize the *Model/State*.